# Crafting magic items and Constructs on the same day

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, constructs

Our group is using the [Downtime rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/downtime/) and I had a question about [crafting Magic items](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation) and [Constructs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/building-and-modifying-constructs/). As a house rule, My character has two downtime actions a day due to having a ring of sustenance, however, this could also be used with the rule allowing you to reduce crafting time to 4 hours by increasing the DC by 5.

The magic item rules state you can only craft one magic item a day. My question is, do constructs count as magic items for the purpose of this rule? So if I finish a magic item in turn 1, can I start building a construct in my second turn on the same day?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about how your houserule(two downtime actions) interacts with the rules.  If I'm correct, that's a question for your DM, not us.

Comment: @godskook No as there is also a rule in the book that lets you reduce crafting time to 4 hours, I could then use the other 4 hours to craft the construct as well so it still applies even without the house rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the rules about [building and modifying constructs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/building-and-modifying-constructs/), they are different process that work very much like each other.

> The Craft Construct feat allows a spellcaster to create all manner of permanent constructs in a process much like magic item creation. [...]
>
> Crafting a construct takes 1 day per 1,000 gp in the item’s base price, excluding any special material costs. This process is **identical to the process for crafting a magic item**, including the rules for accelerating creation and handling interruptions.

But nowhere it says they are the same process and can't be mixed together. The language used on these rules make it sound like it's a different process, or it wouldn't bother saying it's an identical process, it would say it follows [the same rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation), like every other feat of magic item creation that came after the *core rulebook* (example [Inscribe Magical Tattoo](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/inscribe-magical-tattoo-item-creation/)).

That said, the restriction on downtime rules and magic item creation (one item per day) is so you limit the amount of wealth a character can generate in a single day. That limit exists even if you increase the DC to reduce the time taken, so the amount of time required to craft a single item does not affect the limit on *one magic item per day*.

If you GM house-ruled that you have two downtimes per day, then I don't see a problem with allowing to craft magic items (and constructs) twice a day as well. However, since he is house-ruling it, that is something only your GM can answer you.

Comment: I edited my question slightly, I don't believe it would change your answer much but letting you know just in case.

Comment: Just to make sure: the processes are identical but not the same? Is there a way Craft Construct could've been written so the two identical processes *would* be the same?

Comment: Probably: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/inscribe-magical-tattoo-item-creation/

Comment: @Aaron I had already considered it, but will address it aswell.